# Fabric Beta: Tester device ID does not appear after accepting invite

Tags: google-fabric

I've sent several invites to a tester, and he has accepted them on his iPhone 6s, but the device ID does not appear in Fabric. Here's what appears when I view the user:

[Screenshot of user profile in Fabric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk8iN.jpg)

As you can see the iPhone 6s appears under "devices" but the top tab still reads "0 devices" and the UUID cannot be found anywhere. Am I missing something? Is there some reason why his device might be failing to send the UUID?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I haven't seen that happen before. Can you resend them the invite and have them open the link within Safari and not the web-view? There's a Safari icon in the lower-right hand corner they may need to click on when they get the invite after opening the link.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the quick response. We've tried this and the device id is still not appearing (I deleted the tester and re-invited in order to try this).

Comment: Gotcha, in that case I'll need to dig in more and get information such as the app's bundle id and tester info. I'd recommend emailing into support(at)fabric(dot)io with this info a reference to this thread.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help.